# JavaScript validation for mobile phone number that will allow the user to start the number with a specific combinations

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, phone-number

I have been asked to build a landing page with autoresponder SMS and therefore, need the validation to be very strict. Unfortunately I`m not a JavaScript expert.

The number should be limited to 7 digits and it should begin with a few certain combinations only, the combinations are as follows:

```
 050, 044, 066, 099, 073
```

Comment: You should use this: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask. There's a phone extension that makes all the job! Take a look!

Comment: So what have you tried so far? How strict is "very strict"? What would you accept and what would you reject? There's not enough information here.

Comment: We are here to help you solve your problem , but not to write code in your place http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex like this:

```
(050|044|066|099|073)\d{5}
```

Matches one of the three digit combinations you specified and then 5 more digits.

If you want it to tolerate spaces, dashes, brackets and such, then you need to specify that in your question.

There are a ton of other patterns out there that might match your requirement with a little adjustment. See [here](http://www.regxlib.com/%28X%281%29A%28dauMj32U73SPN61bFOiNNizw0GlQWZCP0vH4kqF5168KQMdVWb7WZVHWAPq6F0fn9-yBtSIYJMQL_zp-PNoXiGIQohpebyrN0U126SKwAoF7otMAtIUANDizEqcRO_lmT1HAYgIO66WZQZ_R9AvkPHSaNdxk0VJFOfnRmcYRln-ATOALfnJ1adnVdOhiAKB10%29%29/Search.aspx?k=&c=7&m=-1&ps=20) for example.